# Flex/Bison based compiler - binary generation

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I have a compiler of Pascal subset written using Flex/Bison and C++. As input I use own .pas files. I have noticed that when I run my compiler with those input it works more like an interpreter because I get an instant result. I would like to get the binary file to avoid the need of using the compiler every time. My question is:

What is the best approach to generate binary file?

Comment: If you're parsing to P-code, save the P-code in some format of your own creation. Note this question is way too broad for the Stack Overflow format as this requires multiple things to be done, each of which can be done any number of ways.

Comment: "What is the best approach to generate binary file?" find a good book about compilers, read and understand it. Then implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for example in this way (I done it in this way many years ago):

1. Using Flex/Bison, you have to generate pseudo asm code.
2. In the next step, you have to translate it to macro assembly for the given CPU architecture (x86/ARM/MC68k/PPC/...)
3. Compile output asm file into object file (.o)
4. Link .o file/files with needed libs (.lib) into executable file.

Besides, as commented above, try to find some book about compilers. The best one will be the **Dragon Book**, a kind of compiler bible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

Comment: That is very interesting. Surely I will check this, thank you.